# Why $\ln(1)\neq 2\pi ik$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Given that $e^{2\pi ik}=1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, why isn't $\ln{e^{2\pi  ik}}=2\pi ik$? On the other hand $\ln(1)=0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Because $\ln 1$ is a real number, not a complex.

Comment: look up the definition of $\log$

Comment: You have to do a little bit of "unlearning" when you learn complex analysis. It's true that in the context of real variables $\log 1 = 0$; however as you note, $\log 1$ should be $2\pi ik$. These are not totally at odds. Consider $k=0$.

Comment: You need to read about the complex logarithm and the complex exponential. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: Well, $\ln$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$. You can extend the definition to a simply connected region, and 'pick' a particular value within that region so that $e^{\log z} = z$. By way of intuition, note that $\arcsin$ returns just one of many values that satisfy $\sin y = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By (my) definition of $\log$, for any $x > 0$, $\log x = \int_1^x \frac 1 t dt$.
So $\log 1 = \int_1^1 \frac 1 t dt = 0$.

By some other definition, for any $x > 0$,  $\log x$ is the real number $y$ such that $\exp y = x$ (because$\exp : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R_{>0}$ is bijective). The only real number $y$ such that 
$\exp y = 1$ is $0$ so $\log 1 = 0$.

On the other hand, you have just discovered that the exponential function on complex numbers ( $\exp : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C^*$) is not injective, so there can't be a corresponding inverse function $\log : \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb C$.

Comment: Complex log is multivariable, so 'one" of the values is 1. Is it so?

Comment: @Mathslover personally I think "multi-valued functions" should be avoided whenever possible : always present the facts in terms of $\exp$ and not $\log$ if possible : instead of saying "let $a = \log b$", say instead "pick an $a$ such that $\exp a = b$" and so on. Do not talk, ever, about a value $\log z$ with complex $z$ without making very clear which antecedent by $\exp $ of $z$ you are thinking about. The same applies to the notation $z^w$ which breaks down with complex $z$ and $w$.